# Data retention policy doesn't apply to existing records in data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a data extension which includes a few records. It was not set up a data retention policy in the first place. I have reconfigured the data retention through Contact builder so that individual records would be deleted after 1 day. After over a half day, I rechecked and these records are still there.
Does this reconfiguring data retention apply to existing records in the DE? If it does execute the deletion, when does it happen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All existing records will have the start time be when you set the retention. This is because the entry time of a record to a DE (hidden field `_CreatedDate`) does not exist until you set a data retention rule.

So in your case all previous records will be deleted 1 full day after setting retention and then continue on as expected after.

Comment: I have queried the hidden field you mentioned and it showed the same date time in the DE last modified date. Makes sense to me now! Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know if I missed something but the previous records are still there after over 1 day. I checked the data retention policy again and compared between the hidden field `_CreatedDate` and `getdate()` function in SQL ( May 14 2022 9:41AM vs May 15 2022 5:35PM )

Comment: @duyduc27 - I am honestly not sure on that - I would likely double check the retention to ensure it is set up correctly and if it is not pushing out records despite being set up correctly, I would contact Global Support as they can dive deeper into the issue than we can.

Comment: I believe it's a bug, I recall I read about it somewhere here. I'm working on it with their support though. Will update the result so people can profit.

Comment: @DucLe There is a bug within retention policy itself, especially 1 day retention policy, it's not a true 1 day (24 hours) retention, it's very from around 36ish hours

Comment: @tkhuynh I'm not sure with what you found but the last time when I checked with SF support it didn't work properly and every time they went to check, the records were already cleaned. I gave up and closed the case..

Comment: @DucLe even though you set retention policy of 1 day, your records wont be self deleted after 24 hrs of insertion. It would be 36-40ish hours to be deleted. This is a bug with SF retention policy which is there for a pretty long time already.